# Page layout (page.php) doesn't apply to pages

Tags: wordpress, layout

I made few pages in my admin panel. Then created page.php with this code inside

```
`<?php get_header(); ?>
<section>
    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

Set one of this pages as "homepage". And when i open site it shows me header, footer... everything it should, but when i try to open any of the other pages, I get 404 page...

Help me please, where i have to search for mistakes?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a *front-page.php*, *home.php*, or *index.php* template defined? The front page doesn't use *page.php*.

Comment: non of mentioned, except index.php which is empty. But if I delete everything from page.php, front page will become empty.

Comment: pretty permalinks are on ? just go to settings -> permalinks click save without making any changes and then check if error still persists

Comment: @pr1nc3...That shouldn't matter. The home page doesn't require a "pretty" permalink.

Comment: @rnevious if you have read correctly you will come to know that error is not on homepage

Comment: @pr1nc3...re-read the question. And I quote: `Set one of this pages as "homepage"`. Regardless, there are missing, required templates.

Comment: `Set one of this pages as "homepage". And when i open it it shows me header, footer... everything it should, but when i try to open any of the other pages, I get 404 page... `

Answer (score 0):

You need to define one of the following: **index.php** (REQUIRED), **home.php**, or **front-page.php**.

Here's the way template inheritance works for the home page:

1. WordPress looks for **front-page.php**, regardless of whether or not your site is set up to show a static front page, or your most recent posts
2. If **front-page.php** doesn't exist, WordPress looks for **home.php**
3. If no **home.php** is set, WordPress defaults to **index.php**

You can read more about template inheritance [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: I created a front-page.php, copy there code from page.php and it doesn't help. I still can open a website on homepage, but can't open any of the pages